# What does 1 hint mean in symfony container using factory?

Tags: symfony

I can't understand the meaning of these words

> When using a factory to create services, the value chosen for class has no effect on the resulting service. The actual class name only depends on the object that is returned by the factory. However, the configured class name may be used by compiler passes and therefore should be set to a sensible value.

[Symfony documentation link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html)

I would like to know how to check this in practice, because the meaning of this information is generally not clear to me, and how to check it in the project.

Comment: For most services, the container ends up new'ing the instance using the class parameter.  $service = new $class(); However, for factories the factory takes care of instantiating the object so the class is not needed.  If you look at the compiler code you can do stuff based on class which is why you should set it to a reasonable value. But in most factory cases it is just ignored.